Link a Work Item To Azure DevOps Pipeline as "Integrated in Build" After Pipeline Ended
Sometimes we forget to associate work items to commits (git repository), and so when we do a build the work item is not included in the build's "Related Work Items".  If I update the work item and add that build as a link of type "Integrated in Build":

it is still not included in the build detail under Related Work Items

(note: the 2 related work items are other work items that were associated in commits properly.)
Is there any way to relate work items to a pipeline build after it finishes, and have it show up in Related Work Items?  thank you
